# Ruby on Rails : Search form with keyword and date range does not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datepicker

this is beginner of Ruby on rails.
I'm adding search box in index view and want to search with keyword and date range.
Keyword search works well, but if I contains date range, it returns nothing. bit confused, 
So I post here.

- search action that implemented in Model is like this.

```
def self.search(search, date_from, date_to)

        if !date_from.blank? && !date_to.blank?
            @searched_private_questions = self.where(" asktime BETWEEN ? AND ? ", "#{date_from}", "#{date_to}" )
        else
            @searched_private_questions = PrivateQuestion.all
        end

        if !search.blank?
            #search with user name first
            searched_user = User.where( 'name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%" )
            if !searched_user.empty?
                @searched_private_questions = @searched_private_questions.where(user: searched_user).order(:asktime)
            else
                #if search keyword is not username, search in title and body context
                @searched_private_questions = @searched_private_questions.where('title LIKE ? OR body LIKE ?', "%#{search}%","%#{search}%").order(:asktime)
            end
        else
            @searched_private_questions = @searched_private_questions.order(:asktime)
        end


    end
```

search (keyword) and date_from, date_to parameters are transfered well.
but if I insert date_from and date_to parameters, nothing returns from where clause.

Can be related with pagination code?

- in controller index action is like this:

```
def index
    @searched_private_questions = PrivateQuestion.search(params[:search], params[:date_from], params[:date_to])
    @pagy, @private_questions = pagy(@searched_private_questions, items:10) 
  end
```

I'm using rails 5 and bootstrap 3 with cdn, and bootstrap datepicker. datepicker works well.
I wish someone help me...
Thanks.

Log picture : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP6JQ.png)

Comment: Does the search action return results inside the rails console? Open the console by writing "rails c" and then write "PrivateQuestion.search("", Date.today - 2.years, Date.today + 2.years)"

Comment: @Metaphysiker Yes it does. I checked as you said, and confirmed the result. 
I'd like to add picture of Log in web operation.

Comment: Inside "def index" write "byebug". Then perform a search with dates. Then, inside your console, byebug will open. Enter: "params[:date_from].to_s". What does it say?

Comment: (byebug) params[:date_from].to_s
"05/01/2020"
(byebug) params[:date_to].to_s
"05/19/2020"
----------------------
I got the result as expected..

Comment: Weird. Sorry, I can't help you. Maybe someone else can!

Comment: @Metaphysiker Weird ㅠㅜ anyway thanks a lot! Thank for your attention:)

Answer (score 0):

I found interesting points!!!!!!!!! it works if I execute this in production environment, which connects to PostgreSQL database. Might be related to sqllite settings. Anyway it works in production ENV! Sorry for confusing ;;;